Create Deb package that correctly accesses its python runtime dependencies within deb package
I’ve been trying to create a Deb package for my python project and have the following structure with my app-1.0.0 folder:
app-1.0.0 deb structure
Within app-1.0.0 there is a DEBIAN folder and usr folder. Within the usr folder there is a bin folder that holds my python executable script and share folder. The share folder holds a python cfile and markdown folder that the script imports.
I use the dpkg-deb —-build —-root-owner-group app-1.0.0/ command to build the deb package.
The problem is my script relies on these other python package at runtime and I’m not sure where to correctly place the python folders so that the deb package can correctly access them. Right now I get a  “ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cfile'” when trying to run the application.
I’d like the deb package to access all the python packages it depends on within the deb package so the user does not have to install the packages themselves. Is there a way to do this? I’ve read a lot about shared libraries and symlinks but I don’t have a clear idea of what specific steps and configurations to have to do this. Any help is much appreciated
